# Is it possible to deploy two (2) SiteWise gateway configuration on single EC2 machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-sitewise

I have a Prod and Dev AWS account, and I would like to bring in the live data within the DEV AWS account. The live data is connected to the PROD account via the following path (OPC-UA server -> Greengrass V2 SiteWise Gateway (running on an EC2) -> SiteWise Console). So the question: is it possible to create a new gateway in SiteWise ( in the DEV account) and deploy it on the SAME server running the existing gateway for PROD?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by installing a new Greengrass Core instance on the same server in a *different root folder*. From the SiteWise console, select Create Gateway and go through the Default Setup. Once the installation script has been downloaded, open it and edit the line with:

```
GREENGRASS_FOLDER="/greengrass"
```

replacing `"/greengrass"` with another folder where you want to install the second instance.

If you are installing on Windows, just pass the new folder name as `-InstallPath` parameter to the script.

NOTE: This will not work if you are also installing the data processing pack, as this pack will open some ports that will conflict with those opened by the existing gateway. Also, be careful when you are doing this in a PROD environment.

Courtesy: AWS support on repost community.